# I can't edit permissions in Matomo for a new user

Tags: permissions, analytics, matomo

As a Super User, I have created a new user by clicking the "Add a new user" button. After that, I will edit the permissions for this user (user alum) but I can't with the dropdown.

[image]

I have tried with the "user edit form" > Permissions but I can't see the website.

[image]

What do you suggest?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating the PHP version from 7.0 to 7.1, the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

In your second screenshot, you have set the filter to only show you websites where the user has at least view access. Change this dropdown to view all websites in this list.

Comment: I have set the filter to show all websites and it works, but when I try to change the permissions, the system does not respond. Here a screen recording: https://drive.google.com/file/d/15UAZsQtxEz0M4eS0f-i3yojWs5-aAhzj/view?usp=sharing

Comment: In that case please check the developer tools of your browser and the server log to find out why the request is failing. Maybe you are using a mod_security rule that is blocking the request.